# How can I get envelope expiration info from the DocuSign REST API

Tags: docusignapi

I'm working on a project that creates docusign envelopes via the REST API. I want to be able to customize the expiration date of the envelope. I've been able to do this successfully, but when it comes time to write integration tests, I can't get DocuSign to verify the expiration date of an envelope that I've previously created.

According to the [documentation,](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Get%20Envelope%20Status%20for%20One%20Envelope.htm) I should be able to get an envelope's expiration info by calling `GET` on `/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}`. However, when I actually make that call, I only get some of the fields listed in the example response.

My response:

```
{
  "status": "sent",
  "documentsUri": "/envelopes/UUID/documents",
  "recipientsUri": "/envelopes/UUID/recipients",
  "envelopeUri": "/envelopes/UUID",
  "emailSubject": "Please DocuSign this document: test.pdf",
  "envelopeId": "UUID",
  "customFieldsUri": "/envelopes/UUID/custom_fields",
  "notificationUri": "/envelopes/UUID/notification",
  "enableWetSign": "false",
  "allowMarkup": "false",
  "allowReassign": "false",
  "createdDateTime": "2015-10-17T00:08:31.5930000Z",
  "lastModifiedDateTime": "2015-10-17T00:08:31.5930000Z",
  "sentDateTime": "2015-10-17T00:08:32.2470000Z",
  "statusChangedDateTime": "2015-10-17T00:39:05.4712662Z",
  "documentsCombinedUri": "/envelopes/UUID/documents/combined",
  "certificateUri": "/envelopes/UUID/documents/certificate",
  "templatesUri": "/envelopes/UUID/templates",
  "messageLock": "true",
  "recipientsLock": "false",
  "purgeState": "unpurged"
}
```

In particular, I'm looking for the `notification` field, and its subfields.

Is this a DocuSign bug? Or am I just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this guide has what you are looking for:

https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/rest-api-guide-v2.pdf

Get Envelope Notification Information
This returns the reminder and expiration information for the envelope.
URL:
/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/notification

So if you make a get request to that envelope notification uri you should get the info you are looking for.

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Get Envelope Notification Information was even in the documentation I linked, I just missed it.

If someone from DocuSign sees this, perhaps you could update the example response in Get Individual Envelope Status documentation to remove the fields that aren't actually returned by that call? That would have prevented my confusion.